# How to fix compiler warning on scala.xml.Elem

Tags: xml, scala, compiler-warnings

The following code generates this compilation warning : A repeated case parameter or extracted sequence should be matched only by a sequence wildcard (_*)

```
import scala.xml.Elem
def matchElem(e: Elem) = e match { case <source/> => "match!" }
```

How to fix that ?

Comment: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9343

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `scalac -Xlint:-stars-align,_` to suppress the warning, which is for [this issue](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7623).

Your function looks like `-Xprint:typer`:

```
        def matchElem(e: scala.xml.Elem): String = e match {
          case scala.xml.Elem.unapplySeq(<unapply-selector>) <unapply> (_, "source", _, _) => "match!"
        }
```

To answer your question:

```
$ scala -Xlint
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.6 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_45).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import xml._
import xml._

scala> def matchElem(e: Elem) = e match { case Elem(_, "source", _, _, _*) => "match!" }
matchElem: (e: scala.xml.Elem)String
```

or embed the sequence wildcard in the pattern:

```
scala> <a/> match { case <a/> => }
<console>:8: warning: A repeated case parameter or extracted sequence should be matched only by a sequence wildcard (_*).
       <a/> match { case <a/> => }
                          ^

scala> <a/> match { case <a>{ ns @ _* }</a> if ns.isEmpty => }
```